# Legend in JpGraph

Tags: jpgraph

How can I get nice noticable "square" mark elements in legend, like in this example:

http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_bar6.php

All the time, I'm getting legend like in next example:

http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_line1.php

Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
$graph->legend->SetMarkAbsSize(7);
```

This should give you the squares. Play around with the actual number to alter the size of the squares.